# Can a shortcode function this way

Tags: shortcode

Post body:

```
[paragraph value="1"]text text text[/paragraph]
[paragraph value="2"]moretext moretext moretext[/paragraph]
```

Desired result:

You are reading paragraph **1**: text text text

You are reading paragraph **2**: moretext moretext moretext

Can that be achieve using the above structure cause I couldn't figure out how to do it using the examples at: https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

Can you have enclosing shortcodes and values in them or are these 2 different shortcode types?

Answer (score 7):

Yes. That result can be achieved by single shortcode function. Here is your code-

```
function paragraph_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
    $pull_atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'value' => 0
    ), $atts );
    return 'You are reading paragraph ' . wp_kses_post( $pull_atts[ 'value' ] ) . ': ' . do_shortcode($content);
}
add_shortcode( 'paragraph', 'paragraph_shortcode' );
```

It'll work as you expected. Just input your data as you described-

```
[paragraph value="1"]text text text[/paragraph]
[paragraph value="2"]moretext moretext moretext[/paragraph]
```

An d you'll get your desired output.

Comment: For some reason though Wordpress doesn't interpret it as a paragraph this way?

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. Can you please explain more ? I tested it on my system and it works pretty well. @kat

Comment: OK. I think I found your problem. In your theme files use `<?php the_content();?>` or `<?php echo apply_filters('the_content',$post_content);?>` or `<?php echo apply_filters('the_content',$wp_query->post->post_content);?>`  to render the content. Otherwise the shortcode API will not function.

Comment: It  means that it removes the <p> tags. And even if I add them manually (eg. `return '<p>You are reading paragraph ' . wp_kses_post( $pull_atts[ 'value' ] ) . ': ' . do_shortcode($content).'</p>';`) apparently they're still not interpreted as paragraphs because I have a function that adds an ad code after X number of paragraphs and it doesn't add the code this way => it can't see them as paragraphs.

Comment: Actually its your theme or your system functionality problem. It has nothing to do with this answer.